# WP7 / WPF White space around Image when Stretch="Uniform"

Tags: wpf, silverlight, image, windows-phone-7

I'm working windows phone 7 app which loads an image inside a HyperlinkButton. This works great, except for the `Stretch="Uniform"` causes white space to be put around the image when it is not perfectly square. Is there a way to make this transparent?

[image: White space around image]

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding Id, StringFormat='{}/x;component/Pages/FullScreenImage.xaml?id={0}'}"
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                    toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Background="Transparent">
    <HyperlinkButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Text="Advertised"
                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                    Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="0"
                    Stretch="Uniform" 
                    Source="{Binding ExpectedImage}"  />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </HyperlinkButton.Template>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My image source is creating the white. :-/

Comment: Do you know if this will always be the case? you COULD crop it by loading it into a WritableBitmap - or you could even use pixel detection and a BFS algorithm to get exactly what you're looking for. (In a writable Bitmap, searching for say, the shape starting where it has 3 non-white neighbors). It depends on how you're using it, and whether it's worth the probable performance issues. You could also make your app 'strongly-themed' and no longer support black backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I found out I have control over the image source, so I can change the cropping style of the images coming back.